# valgrind memcheck reports false positive?

Tags: memory-leaks, alignment, valgrind

Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf1[100];
char buf2[100];

int main()
{
    char **p = (char**)(buf1+sizeof(long));
    char **q = (char**)(buf2+1);
    *p = (char*)malloc(100);
    *q = (char*)malloc(100);

    strcpy(*p, "xxxx");
    strcpy(*q, "zzzz");

    printf("p:%s   q:%s\n", *p, *q);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code using gcc, and run valgrind-3.6.1 like this

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file=test.log  --show-reachable=yes  ~/a.out
```

valgrind gave me the log below

```
==20768== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20768== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20768== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20768== Command: /home/zxin11/a.out
==20768== Parent PID: 12686
==20768== 
==20768== 
==20768== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20768==     in use at exit: 200 bytes in 2 blocks
==20768==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 200 bytes allocated
==20768== 
==20768== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==20768==    at 0x4C2488B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==20768==    by 0x4005FD: main (test2.c:12)
==20768== 
==20768== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==20768==    at 0x4C2488B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==20768==    by 0x400611: main (test2.c:13)
==20768== 
==20768== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20768==    definitely lost: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==20768==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20768==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20768==    still reachable: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==20768==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20768== 
==20768== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20768== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 3 from 3)
```

Why the first malloc was still reachable while the second malloc was definitely lost?
Maybe it's about alignment, you can't put the address of malloced memory into an un-aligned variable, if so, how can I suppress this kind of positive report?
Think you very much.

Answer (score 5):

From the [memcheck manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks) (emphasis mine):

> If `--leak-check` is set appropriately, for each remaining block, Memcheck determines if the block is reachable from pointers within the root-set. The root-set consists of (a) general purpose registers of all threads, and (b) **initialised, aligned, pointer-sized data words** in accessible client memory, including stacks.

So your conjecture about alignment was correct.  Unfortunately, the best way to robustly suppress such a warning is probably just to copy any such known values into aligned locations before exiting your program (presumably this code is a mock-up for your real application, where it makes some sort of sense for you to store unaligned pointers).

You can also try [writing or generating a suppression file](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) with `--gen-suppressions=yes`.  But if your application is non-deterministic or you run it with different input data, this approach will get annoying pretty quickly.